# Laravel 5: files (.doc/.pdf) storage with security

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have been developing a job posting website using Laravel 5.3. One of my functions is to allow users (job seekers) to upload their resumes (.doc/.pdf) into the storage folder. But I don't know how make it more secure that only authenticated employers can download their resumes. Please advise how to name the files while uploading and how to store them with security.

Thank you.

Comment: Just add the `auth` middleware to your download routes.

Comment: create a middleware that checks if user is authenticated employer or just an  employer then add this to your route.

Comment: Thank you. I've created two middlewares now- "employer" and "jobseeker". Could you give me sample coding with route please?

Comment: One more function is to allow an employer to download application, which are applied to his jobs only?